# Remove script file from /etc/profile.d/ when can't login

Tags: boot, login

I added `.sh` file to `/etc/profile.d`. Now my laptop just gets stuck at login prompt - showing it over and over again. Is there any way to access and remove this script? Ubuntu Live treats my filesystem as read-only

Comment: Login from the TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F2)?

Comment: The same thing. I also tried Ubuntu recovery mode's CLI but it treats FS as read-only

Comment: In recovery mode, did you mount it as rw? `mount -rw -o remount /`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mount anything manually. Just answered the prompts. So should I mount it by myself?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Well now I'll try and come back later

Comment: Thanx, muru. You're a guru!!

Comment: @muru your answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recovery mode, unless you use the root shell with networking option, you need to manually mount `/` for writing:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```